# static member function error in c++

Tags: c++

If static class member and static class function has a class scope then why can't I access the display function(it shows error)? If in place of display function I write count it displays the correct value i.e., 0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
     static int Length;
     static void display()
     {
        cout<< ++Length;
     }
};

int Person::Length=0;

int main()
{
   cout<< Person :: display(); //error
   // Person :: Length shows correct value
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* call the `display` function, your error is that you are trying to output the result to `cout`. `Person::display` doesn't return anything, hence the error.

Just change this:

```
cout<< Person :: display(); //error
```

To this:

```
Person::display();
```

Comment: but why does it work with the static members and not with the static member function? cout<<Person :: Length prints correct value

Comment: Because `Person::Length` is an int. `Person::display()` returns nothing. You can't output nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pipe objects into streams, you need to define an appropriate operator <<, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
     class Displayable {
         template< typename OStream >
         friend OStream& operator<< (OStream& os, Displayable const&) {
             os << ++Person::Length;
             return os;
         }
     };
     static int Length;
     static Displayable display() { return {}; }
};

int Person::Length=0;

int main()
{
   cout<< Person :: display(); //works
   // Person :: Length shows correct value
   return 0;
}
```